# how to receive data(with input tag) in node.js and store in mogodb

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I had input form and submit button and how to insert this data in nodejs and then mongoDB? please give me links or tips :)

```
<form method="post" ...>
<input placeholder="Name & Surname">
<button type="submit>
</form>
```

Comment: Create a REST API using Express. Use Mongoose to wire up with MongoDB

Comment: aadarshsg Thanx, i will try this :)

Comment: Sometime I wish we had a flag rtfm. Anyway, read [this about mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) and [this about node](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/handle-get-post-request-express-4/)

Comment: i can't do this and can you give me some code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect a straightforward couple of lines. Do you have NodeJS and MongoDB setup and ready to use? Do you have a framework selected? I'd say lack of details.

You could use the following for a head start:

- [THE DEAD-SIMPLE STEP-BY-STEP GUIDE FOR FRONT-END DEVELOPERS TO
  GETTING UP AND RUNNING WITH NODE.JS, EXPRESS, JADE, AND MONGODB](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/)
- [CREATING A SIMPLE RESTFUL WEB APP WITH NODE.JS, EXPRESS, AND
  MONGODB](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/)